# I have seaweed salad with sesame flavor. What are some good ways to garnish it or nice things to garnish with it?

Tags: asian-cuisine

I'm curious for some ideas on what to make with seaweed salad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to dress the seaweed salad in a vinaigrette made with:

Soy Sauce: 1 1/2 tbsp

Sugar: 1 1/2 tbsp

Vinegar: 1 tbsp

Sesame Seeds: 1/2 tbsp to 1 tbsp

Sesame Oil: 1 tsp

Red Pepper Powder: 1/4 tsp

I eat the seaweed salad with steamed white rice.

Answer (score 3):

Asian style - usually with a sprinkle of white sesame on top and that's it.

Comment: hehe, that's what it already had.